# Dashlets do not render on 4.6.12, php 5.5.38 (Drupal 7)

Tags: dashboard

Dashlets do not render.

I know similar questions have been asked before, so I'll try to be as specific as possible in this one. Not sure what sensible next steps would be to debug this.

The backtrace is as follows:

```
#0 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(566): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("Malformed response", 16, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(1225): PEAR->raiseError("Malformed response", 16)
#5 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(753): HTTP_Response->process(TRUE, TRUE)
#6 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System.php(1393): HTTP_Request->sendRequest()
#7 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Dashboard.php(329): CRM_Utils_System::getServerResponse("http://[SITE_DOMAIN]/civicrm/dashlet/getting-started?reset=1&snippet=5")
#8 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/AJAX.php(606): CRM_Core_BAO_Dashboard::getDashletInfo(2)
#9 [internal function](): CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::dashboard()
#10 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(278): call_user_func((Array:2))
#11 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:12))
#12 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#13 [SITE_ROOT]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(482): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#14 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("ajax", "dashboard")
#15 [SITE_ROOT]/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#16 [SITE_ROOT]/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#17 {main}
```

I've checked the following:

- `curl http://[SITE_DOMAIN]` works from the server command line
- http://[SITE_DOMAIN]/civicrm/dashlet/getting-started?reset=1&snippet=5 works from the browser I'm using on this site
- Dashlets load for the same site on a local development machine
- Dashlets load on civicrm 4.7.12 on the same server
- CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL in civicrm.settings.php = the URL I'm calling

Adding `var_dump($line);` after sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php:1223 gives `string(0) ""`

Any ideas on sensible next steps?